# Why does using Technic Launcher modpacks slow Minecraft down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, framerate

I can play *normal* Minecraft at 60 FPS, on the highest settings. When I launch a Technic Launcher modpack, Minecraft will run at a maximum of 4 FPS.

I have a Qosmio gaming computer, running Java 7 64-bit. It will not run at all with Java 8 64-bit. I have allocated 7GB of RAM, and tried setting all the settings to the lowest possible configurations;

- **Render distance**: tiny.
- **Clouds**: off.
- **Particles**: minimal.
- **Smooth lighting**: off.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: How much RAM are you allocating for the Technic Launcher Modpack? The technic Launcher Modpack has to load multiple mode in conjunction with vanilla. Try to allocate more RAM in the launcher.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft"…](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. It's not off-topic if the game runs fine without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your RAM allocation? I haven't used Technic in years, but I assume it still defaults to 1GB. Try upping that (there should be an options menu before on the launcher)

Comment: My ram allocation is set to 7GB, that's why I had to go back to java 7 64-bit , with java 8 64-bit it only allowed 1GB RAM access, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Set it down to 2-4GB, I've heard of issues with setting ram above 4GB (it's weird, but apparently minecraft is not coded to use that much ram well)

Answer (score 0):

We released with a bug that causes Technic to eat up CPU on one core while Minecraft is running.  Depending on how many cores your machine has, this could have very serious consequences for playing Minecraft.  There is a fix on the Beta stream, so you can try Launcher Options -> Launcher Build -> Beta Stream and see if your performance improves.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Technic Launcher, then click on launcher options at the top right. Explore the options until you find RAM, The most RAM you can use is 5 GB on technic. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Same thing happened to me, just install Java Offline x64.